# How to disabled spring-security by application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'd trying to activate `basic authentication` with password hash encryption.

```
@Configuration //gets picked up automatically by spring-boot
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.userDetailsService(details).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

I want the authentication only being active in production. So I'm trying to deactivate it in general at first, use:

`security.basic.enabled=false`

Result: the application is still secured. I'm presented with the username/password screen.

But how could I then disable the need for authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved with `ConditionalOnProperty`:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("security.basic.enabled")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To do different things in different environments you should use [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Suppose you need security configuration bean only in production environment, then you should mark it to be loaded conditionally when a specific profile is enabled.

```
@Configuration //gets picked up automatically by spring-boot
@Profile("Production")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.userDetailsService(details).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Profile specific configuration is done in properties files named `application-{profile}.properties` and `bootstrap-{profile}.properties` files.

Now since security configuration bean is marked with profile `Production` it will be loaded only when `Production` profile is enabled.

To enable a profile you have to set following property.

```
#One or more profiles can be active simultaneously
spring.profiles.active=Production,Dev,Local
```

This property can either be edited in the common properties file `application.properties` (Always loaded unlike profile specific properties files like `application-Production.properties` which are conditionally loaded) or it can provided as a environment variable as below.

```
On Windows
set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=Production
On Unix
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=Production
```

It can be done using a million other ways that spring supports to load properties. For a list of all the methods go through this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Finally to disable default Spring security (Basic) Autoconfiguration, you can use following properties.

```
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false #For actuator
```

Above should be in the profile specific properties files where you wish to disable Spring Security auto configuration.

Comment: As written above, I already tried using `security.basic.enabled=false`, which should normally work, but does not when using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter `.

Comment: That's because `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is still creating a bean, that will have to be conditionally loaded, as mentioned at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: I extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter twice and worked as above described. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

To disable spring-security autoconfiguration entirely use the following property

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[0]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```